# SLURM - forcing MPI to schedule different ranks on different physical CPUs

Tags: mpi, slurm

I am running an experiment on an 8 node cluster under SLURM. Each CPU has 8 physical cores, and is capable of hyperthreading. When running a program with

```
#SBATCH --nodes=8
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=8

mpirun -n 64 bin/hello_world_mpi
```

it schedules two ranks on the same physical core. Adding the option

```
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-core=1
```

gives an error, SLURM saying "Batch job submission failed: Requested node configuration is not available". Is it somehow only allocating 4 physical cores per node? How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you please provide the output of command `sinfo -o%C`

Comment: Also, did you mean `--ntasks-per-core` ? You could also use `--cpus-per-task`

Comment: if you use `mpirun`, then the binding is done by the MPI library. If you are using Open MPI, it would bind a task to a NUMA domain by default, pass `--bind-to core` to have one MPI task pinned to a single core. If you want SLURM to do the process binding, then use `srun`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the available CPU information in your cluster using `sinfo -o%C`.

I wasn't able to find any `--ntasks-per-cpu` for SBATCH in the documentation. You could try the following options for SBATCH `--ntasks-per-core`. As per documentation:

> --ntasks-per-core=
> Request the maximum ntasks be invoked on each core. Meant to be used with the --ntasks option. Related to --ntasks-per-node except at
> the core level instead of the node level. This option will be
> inherited by srun.

You could also try `--cpus-per-task`.

> c, --cpus-per-task=
> Advise the Slurm controller that ensuing job steps will require ncpus number of processors per task. Without this option, the
> controller will just try to allocate one processor per task.

Also please note:

> Beginning with 22.05, srun will not inherit the --cpus-per-task
> value requested by salloc or sbatch. It must be requested again with
> the call to srun or set with the SRUN_CPUS_PER_TASK environment
> variable if desired for the task(s).

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed that the MPI library did the binding. srun is not installed, but with mpirun (no -n 64), it works.